# Excel Index Autofill over different Sheets

Tags: excel, indexing

I want to recieve data from several sheets into one sheet and I want to use  Autofill, because there are a lot of sheets.

Example: =INDEX(Sheet2!F20;0;0)

When I draw it do the right, it should change into =INDEX(Sheet3!F20;0;0) / =INDEX(Sheet4!F20;0;0) etc.

When I draw it to the bottom, it should change into =INDEX(Sheet2!F21;0;0) / =INDEX(Sheet2!F22;0;0) etc.

Is there any way to achieve this or do I have to use VBA?

kind regards
Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sheet2, cell F20:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet" & COLUMN(B:B) & "!F" & ROW(20:20))
```

Drawing right goes up in sheet number:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet" & COLUMN(C:C) & "!F" & ROW(20:20))
=INDIRECT("sheet" & COLUMN(D:D) & "!F" & ROW(20:20))
```

And drawing down goes up in row number:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet" & COLUMN(B:B) & "!F" & ROW(21:21))
=INDIRECT("sheet" & COLUMN(B:B) & "!F" & ROW(22:22))
```